# Have there been any studies on the mass/energy that thoughts produce?

Tags: energy, mass-energy

I am very interested in the concept of energy and manifesting a desired reality (which is more so thought of as spiritual or metaphysical rather than scientific). However, I do believe there is a scientific explanation and therefore, believe that thoughts must carry some form of mass and was wondering if there were any studies on this.  And if not, where would one begin to start looking into this area?

Comment: Energy is the conserved quantity associated with time translation symmetry. Could you explain how that relates to anything "spiritual" or metaphysical?

Comment: How much energy is required for person X get to any particular desired reality (based on their current environmental circumstance)?  I only said “spiritual” because the concept of manifestation is usually associated with the spiritual community.  However, I believe there is actually a science behind manifesting and it has all to do with energy placement (including that of your thoughts) and that’s where my question was coming from.

Answer (score 2):

Thoughts are an arrangement, not an object. For a very crude analogy, consider the difference between an object and a video of the object. The video is a series of pixel arrangements arranged in time. It does not have any significant mass or energy, although it takes some energy to run the machine that plays it. You can edit the video or delete it and replace it with a new video, just by rearranging how the pixels turn off and on. Likewise, a thought is an arrangement of chemicals and electrical signals. It does take some energy to carry on thinking, and of course your brain has mass, but the energy is not spent creating new objects, but running the machine (your brain) that rearranges chemicals and electrical signals into brief patterns.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Actually, it was very useful.  My question has now been closed for being "off-topic", but I appreciate your time to respond to me.